# Get readable content array keys when using Layout Discovery and layouts templates

Tags: theming, 8

I noticed when using Layout Discovery on nodes display modes, the content array looks like this.

[image]

Compared to the content array without using Layout Discovery which looks like this :

[image]

A counterpart of this is that it makes it harder to alter fields inside templates.
I understand this is because fields are wrapped inside blocks, and those blocks are giving their id as keys.
I kind of fixed it this way

```
function theme_preprocess_layout(&$variables) {
  // Replace complicated hashes keys by field names
  // to allow customization under layout templates.
  // Applied to fields as blocks only (not views, custom blocks, etc.).
  foreach (Element::children($variables['content']) as $name) {
    foreach ($variables['content'][$name] as $key => $value) {
      if (substr( $key, 0, 1 ) !== "#" && isset($value['content']['#field_name'])) {
        $newkey = $value['content']['#field_name'];
        $variables['content'][$name][$newkey] = $variables['content'][$name][$key];
        unset($variables['content'][$name][$key]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which render this content array afterwards (I did not test on display modes for other entity types):

[image]

And allows doing that kind of things under e.g. `layout.html.twig` :

```
{% if content.header['field_video'] %}
  {{ content.header|without('field_image') }}
{% else %}
  {{ content.header }}
{% endif %}
```

I have the feeling that we are losing the great feature of twig filters on fields that are part of node templates here.

So, did someone came into the same issue and did you find another way to bypass this?